# virtual operator float()

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I'd like to know the meaning of the `virtual operator float()` method in the following code ,
is it used for casting ?

```
#include <iostream>

class Frac
{
  protected:
int a, b;
  public: 
    Frac(int x, int y):a(x),b(y)
    {}

    virtual operator float()
     {  return (float)a/b; }

    friend void Print(Frac var)
     {   std::cout << var << endl; }
};


class TwiceFrac : public Frac
{
  public:
    TwiceFrac():Frac(1,2)
{}
    virtual operator float()
{ return (float)a/b * 2; }
};

int main()
{
    TwiceFrac obj;
    Print(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code defines an implicit conversion for an object of the class to a `float` variable. When you do `cout << var << endl;` the `operator float` is invoked on `var` object to convert it to the `float` and the `float` value returned is printed.

The `virtual` keyword allows the derived class to override the function defined in the base class. To take advantage of this polymorphism you need to change the signature of `Print` function to take the *reference* of Fanc (i.e. `Print(Franc& var)`). Then depending on the type of the object passed to the function, appropriate `operator float` will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. this operator used for casting :)

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because you **slice** in the Print function.

You need to get your Print function to take a reference. More preferably make it take a const reference and make your implicit type conversion method also const.